# Failed to read the image with Tensorflow shuffle_batch() function within user defined function

Tags: python, image-processing, tensorflow, computer-vision

I am trying to read the images and relevant labels using `shuffle_batch()` function with my user-defined function, But it seems cannot start the reading file queue.

**1.My Questiones:**

1. Why can not the code read images successfully with calling shuffle_batch() in my user-defined function?
2. How to fix the problem?

**2.Code with user defined function**

**Note print1,2,3 in Session() part.**

```
# Global Variable
# Image info
IMG_HEIGHT = 64
IMG_WIDTH = 64
CHANEL = 3

# File stream
BATCH_SIZE = 128

# Training parameter
LEARNING_RATE = 0.001
TRAINING_ITERS = 100
KEEP_PROB = 0.5
DISPLAY_EPOCH = 1

# Filepath
image_filepath = 'Image_P/'


import tensorflow as tf

def read_data(fold):
    '''
    Args:
        fold: int8, (for K fold cross validation)
    Returns:
        batch: tensor, batch_shape = ((BATCH_SIZE, IMG_HEIGHT, IMG_WIDTH, CHANEL),(BATCH_SIZE, 3)), 
                dtype = tf.float32
    '''
    csv_path = tf.train.string_input_producer(['label_3D'+str(fold)+'.csv'])
    textReader = tf.TextLineReader()
    _, csv_content = textReader.read(csv_path)
    im_name, col_2, col_3, col_4 = tf.decode_csv(csv_content, record_defaults=[[""], [1], [1], [1]])
    label = tf.pack([col_2, col_3, col_4])


    # load images
    im_content = tf.read_file(image_filepath + im_name+'.jpeg')
    image = tf.image.decode_jpeg(im_content, channels=3)
    image_float32 = tf.divide(tf.cast(image, tf.float32), 255.0)


    # Generate shuffle batch
    batch_shape = ((IMG_HEIGHT, IMG_WIDTH, CHANEL),(3))
    batch = tf.train.shuffle_batch([image_float32, label], 
                                    batch_size = BATCH_SIZE, 
                                    capacity = BATCH_SIZE * 50, 
                                    min_after_dequeue = BATCH_SIZE * 10, 
                                    shapes = batch_shape)
    return batch



with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

    # Start reading file queue
    coord = tf.train.Coordinator()
    threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners(coord=coord)

    fold = 0

    print(read_data(fold)) # print1

    a = read_data(fold)
    print(a) # print2

    b = sess.run(read_data(fold))
    print(b) # print3

    #End reading file queue
    coord.request_stop()
    coord.join(threads)
```

**Print result of code with user defined function**

print1 works exactly the same as print2:

```
[<tf.Tensor 'shuffle_batch:0' shape=(128, 64, 64, 3) dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'shuffle_batch:1' shape=(128, 3) dtype=int32>]
```

print3 is always stuck with nothing display on the console(No matter what order they are)

**3.Code without user defined function**

It is almost the same as the code with user defined function.

```
# Global Variable
# Image info
IMG_HEIGHT = 64
IMG_WIDTH = 64
CHANEL = 3

# File stream
BATCH_SIZE = 128

# Training parameter
LEARNING_RATE = 0.001
TRAINING_ITERS = 100
KEEP_PROB = 0.5
DISPLAY_EPOCH = 1

# Filepath
image_filepath = 'Image_P/'


import tensorflow as tf



csv_path = tf.train.string_input_producer(['label_3D'+str(0)+'.csv'])
textReader = tf.TextLineReader()
_, csv_content = textReader.read(csv_path)
im_name, col_2, col_3, col_4 = tf.decode_csv(csv_content, record_defaults=[[""], [1], [1], [1]])
label = tf.pack([col_2, col_3, col_4])


# load images
im_content = tf.read_file(image_filepath + im_name+'.jpeg')
image = tf.image.decode_jpeg(im_content, channels=3)
image_float32 = tf.divide(tf.cast(image, tf.float32), 255.0)


# Generate shuffle batch
batch_shape = ((IMG_HEIGHT, IMG_WIDTH, CHANEL),(3))
batch = tf.train.shuffle_batch([image_float32, label], 
                                batch_size = BATCH_SIZE, 
                                capacity = BATCH_SIZE * 50, 
                                min_after_dequeue = BATCH_SIZE * 10, 
                                shapes = batch_shape)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

    # Start reading file queue
    coord = tf.train.Coordinator()
    threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners(coord=coord)

    fold = 0

    print(read_data(fold)) # print1

    a = read_data(fold)
    print(a) # print2

    b = sess.run(read_data(fold))
    print(b) # print3

    #End reading file queue
    coord.request_stop()
    coord.join(threads)
```

**4.Print result of code without user defined function**

print1 and print2 works again with the same result:

```
[<tf.Tensor 'shuffle_batch_1:0' shape=(128, 64, 64, 3) dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'shuffle_batch_1:1' shape=(128, 3) dtype=int32>]
```

print3 also works:

```
[array([[[[ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ],
         [ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ],
         [ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ],
         ..., 
         [ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ],
         [ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ],
         [ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ]],

        [[ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ],
         [ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ],
         [ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ],
         ..., 
         [ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ],
         [ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ],
         [ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ]],

        [[ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ],
         [ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ],
         [ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ],
         ..., 
         [ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ],
         [ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ],
         [ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ]],

        ..., 
        [[ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ],
         [ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ],
         [ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ],
         ..., 
         [ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ],
         [ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ],
         [ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ]],

        [[ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ],
         [ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ],
         [ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ],
         ..., 
         [ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ],
         [ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ],
         [ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ]],

        [[ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ],
         [ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ],
         [ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ],
         ..., 
         [ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ],
         [ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ],
         [ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ]]],


       [[[ 0.02352941,  0.        ,  0.        ],
         [ 0.        ,  0.00392157,  0.        ],
         [ 0.        ,  0.01568628,  0.        ],
         ...,
```

Comment: This usually means there's not enough items available to fill a batch so it's waiting forever. You can try batch size 1 and wrap each node in `tf.Print` to get some visibility of what's getting executed.

Comment: thanks, the `tf.print(a,[a])` invokes an error in InteractiveSession() in my code with user defined function: `TypeError: Cannot convert a list containing a tensor of dtype <dtype: 'int32'> to <dtype: 'float32'> (Tensor is: <tf.Tensor 'shuffle_batch_4:1' shape=(1, 3) dtype=int32>)`But I have already convert all int to float. Does it means it cannot read any data? But what's more important is how to sove it?

Comment: `Print` arguments must be all of the same type, are you trying to print labels and image using same `Print` statement? (your labels are `int`). To solve it you need to make sure you are able to read stuff and you have enough for fill a batch (you need more than 1k entries because of `min_after_dequeue`)

Comment: thanks, I have change batch_size to 5 and tried `tf.Print(a[1],[a[1]]).eval()` . But it is stuck agian. Therefore, I think the problem is that it cannot read file with user defined function.  Do you have any fix suggestion?

Comment: my suggestion is to wrap all your ops with `tf.Print` (ie, like csv_content = tf.Print(....csv_content...)`, and isolate the problem a little better. IE, does it dequeue anything at all? Does it dequeue, but not enough to fill the batch?

Comment: I have change the result of the function to csv_content, and try `tf.Print(csv_content).eval()`, it is stuck a again. But when I try `tf.Print(csv_content).eval()` without calling the user-defined function, it comes out with a result `b'14481_left,0,1,0'`. So it seems the code with user-defined function cannot start to read the csv file? What's wrong with that? Can you give me some advice? thanks!

Comment: My advice is to wrap every step of you input pipeline with tf.Print so that you can isolate the problem a little. IE, do csv_content=tf.Print(..csv_content), as well as all the other tensors